# Can I Merge Footer in GridView?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, html

I have a GridView that is bound with a dataset.  I have my footer, whichis separated by the column lines.  I want to merge 2 columns; how do I do that?

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name">
<ItemTemplate>
...  
</ItemTemplate>
<FooterTemplate >                    
Grand Total:
</div>
</FooterTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Age" SortExpression="Age">
<ItemTemplate>
...  
</ItemTemplate>
<FooterTemplate >                    
<%# GetTotal() %> 
</div>
</FooterTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: You're looking for a ColumnSpan... - http://www.dotnetjunkies.com/WebLog/joshuagough/archive/2006/06/23/141038.aspx - http://forums.asp.net/t/1270422.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

untested code

1st footer template should include <%# GetTotal() %>

2nd footer template should be empty

```
    Protected Sub Page_SaveStateComplete(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.SaveStateComplete
        Dim DG As GridView = GridView1
            Dim Tbl As Table = DG.Controls(0)
            Dim tr As GridViewRow
            Dim i As Integer
            Dim j As Integer

tr = Tbl.Rows(Tbl.Rows.Count - 1) 'this line assume last row is footer row

                    tr.Cells(0).ColumnSpan = 2 'if you have 3 columns then colspan = 3 instead

                    For j = 1 To 1 'if you have 3 columns then j = 1 To 2 instead
                        tr.Cells(j).Visible = False
                    Next

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 8):

```
protected void GridView1_OnRowDataBound(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
        {
           e.Row.Cells.RemoveAt(1);
           e.Row.Cells[0].ColumnSpan = 2;

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I was doing something like this - trying to have a button, in the footer span multiple cols.

I ran into a problem when I set columnspan via code, because a) I'm a noob, and b) it was *not* doing what I expected.  I don't remember all the details, but there was some kind of gotcha in there - like it was adding extra columns or something.

Here was my solution.  Maybe some of it will be useful.  I did in the prerender for the gridview (gvDocs).

And what got it working correctly for me, was programatically removing cells of the footer as well as setting the columnspan.

Even if the code doesn't help, maybe people will get a laugh at the encroaching forgetfulness afflicting me.  It makes me laugh sometimes.

```
   Protected Sub gvDocs_PreRender(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles gvDocs.PreRender

        If gvDocs.Rows.Count > 0 Then


            Dim m As Integer = gvDocs.FooterRow.Cells.Count
            For i As Integer = m - 1 To 1 Step -1
                If i <> 8 Then '7 is the number of the column with the applychanges button in it.
                    gvDocs.FooterRow.Cells.RemoveAt(i)
                End If
            Next i
            gvDocs.FooterRow.Cells(1).ColumnSpan = 6 '6 is the number of visible columns to span.
        End If
    End Sub
```

Fernando68 - Here it is in C#

```
protected void gvDocs_PreRender(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{

    if (gvDocs.Rows.Count > 0) {

        int m = gvDocs.FooterRow.Cells.Count;
        for (int i = m - 1; i >= 1; i += -1) {
            //7 is the number of the column with the applychanges button in it.
            if (i != 8) {
                gvDocs.FooterRow.Cells.RemoveAt(i);
            }
        }
        gvDocs.FooterRow.Cells[1].ColumnSpan = 6;
        //6 is the number of visible columns to span.
    }
}

//=======================================================
//Service provided by Telerik (www.telerik.com)
//Conversion powered by NRefactory.
//Twitter: @telerik
//Facebook: facebook.com/telerik
//=======================================================
```

EDITED - Needed to use square brackets to access cell by index in the footer row

Comment: @Fernando68 - C# added